# Problema com ("select username, pontos from data order by pontos desc limit 10");

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando fazer um sistema de ranking, onde aparece o nome de usuário e a pontuação. Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
$select = $mysqli->query("select username, pontos from data order by pontos desc limit 10");
  $row = $select->num_rows;
  $get = $select->fetch_array();
  $top_1 = $get[0];
  $top_1_pontos = $get[1];
  $top_2 = $get[2];
  $top_2_pontos = $get[3];
```

Usando um echo no `$top_1` ele exibe o nome do usuário com a maior pontuação.

Usando um echo no `$top_1_pontos` ele exibe a pontuação do usuário.

A partir do `$top_1_pontos` ele não exibe mais nada... o quê eu fiz de errado?

Qual a forma correta pra se obter o ranking buscando todos os usuários e listando os 10 melhores?

O MySql é mais ou menos assim:

```
INSERT INTO `data` (`id`,`username`,`pontos`) VALUES 
(1,'Joao',9321),
(2,'Maria',151000),
(3,'Pedro',21201),
(4,'Jose',31252),
(5,'Antonio',131145),
(6,'Adriano',13211),
(7,'Marcelo',6897),
(8,'Juliana',53144);
```

Comment: Quantos registros tem na tabela? Você já experimentou dar um print_r no $get para ver tudo que ele trás?

Comment: Está só a selecionar o username e os pontos na sua query, ou seja $get[2] já não tem nada. Até devia ter dado erro `undefined index...`

Comment: Hey, mas ai você pediu pra exibir só username e pontos, e nada mais... porque não fez um foreach() pra listar os registros com as devidas pontuações? Vc pode colar seu SQL aqui, e montamos um exemplo prático

Comment: Editei com os dados André, ela é mais ou menos daquele jeito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário 1 fetch para ler cada registro. Portanto, repita o fetch após mostrar os dados do top_1. (e use os índices 0 e 1 novamente)

Se quiser mostrar todos os 10, é mais prático colocar seu fetch dentro da condição de um while.

EDIT: como tu atualizou tua pergunta, atualizo minha resposta. Segue o trecho de código em questão:

```
while($get = $select->fetch_array()) {
  $nome = $get[0];
  $pontos = $get[1];
  //faz algo com $nome e $pontos
}
```

Isso vai ler os nomes e pontuação dos 10 primeiros.

Comment: O responsável pelo downvote poderia explicar?

Comment: Bacana, funcionou!